# how to solve this "cannot find reference" problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

so when I import this module in pycharm as follow:

```
from bs4 import beautifulsoup
```

it gives me this error:

```
Cannot find reference "beautifulsoup" in "__init__.py"
```

I searched for it but I don't know how to solve it I am a beginner btw and I use python 3.9.1

Comment: you have installed it right? pip install beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, import statement should be this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

after assuming you have installed it already with `pip`:

```
pip install bs4
```